# Coding a simple platformer game and enemies won't show up

Tags: actionscript-3

I have been having a problem getting enemies to appear and this is the final stretch before I can get the game to fully work.

It was supposed to be a one off, the original plan was to have enemies spawning, but the coordinates I have laid out for the enemies have not worked.

I will attach the main code and the enemy `.as` file, using `actionscript3`.

```
// MAIN TIME LINE CODE

import flash.events.Event;

var leftPressed:Boolean = false;
var rightPressed:Boolean = false;
var upPressed:Boolean = false;
var downPressed:Boolean = false;
//buttong pressing

var leftBumping:Boolean = false;
var rightBumping:Boolean = false;
var upBumping:Boolean = false;
var downBumping:Boolean = false;
// collision variables

var leftBumpPoint:Point = new Point(-30, -55);
var rightBumpPoint:Point = new Point(30, -55);
var upBumpPoint:Point = new Point(0, -120);
var downBumpPoint:Point = new Point(0, 0);
// character collision

var gravityConstant:Number = 1.5;
var jumpConstant:Number = - 35;
var maxSpeedConstant:Number = 18;
//jumping

var animationState:String = "idle";
// for the animation

var bulletList:Array = new Array();
var enemyList:Array = new Array();

var currentLevel:int = 1;

var scrollX:Number = 0;
var scrollY:Number = 500;
//parralax

var xSpeed:Number = 0;
var ySpeed:Number = 0;
// speeeeeed

var speedConstant:int = 5;

var friction:Number = 0.9;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);

addEnemiesToLevel1();

function addEnemiesToLevel1():void {
    addEnemy(340, 390);
  /*  addEnemy(900, -490);
    addEnemy(2005, -115);
    addEnemy(1225, -875);*/
    //adds an enemy
}



function loop(e:Event):void{
    if(back.hitTestPoint(player.x + leftBumpPoint.x, player.y + leftBumpPoint.y, true)){
        trace("leftBumping");
        leftBumping = true;
    } else {
        leftBumping = false;
    }

    if(back.hitTestPoint(player.x + rightBumpPoint.x, player.y + rightBumpPoint.y, true)){
        trace("rightBumping");
        rightBumping = true;
    } else {
        rightBumping = false;
    }

    if(back.hitTestPoint(player.x + upBumpPoint.x, player.y + upBumpPoint.y, true)){
        trace("upBumping");
        upBumping = true;
    } else {
        upBumping = false;
    }

    if(back.hitTestPoint(player.x + downBumpPoint.x, player.y + downBumpPoint.y, true)){
        trace("downBumping");
        downBumping = true;
    } else {
        downBumping = false;
    }   


    if(leftPressed){
        xSpeed -= speedConstant;
        /*player.x -= xSpeed;*/
        player.scaleX = -1;
            trace("fff");

    } else if(rightPressed) {
        xSpeed += speedConstant;
        /*player.x += xSpeed;*/
        player.scaleX = 1;
// player movement left and right
    }

    /*player.scaleX = 1;*/ // copy in case

    /*if(upPressed){
        ySpeed -= speedConstant;

    } else if(downPressed){
        ySpeed += speedConstant;

    }*/

    if(leftBumping){
        if(xSpeed < 0){
            xSpeed *= -0.5;
        }
    }

    if(rightBumping){
        if(xSpeed > 0){
            xSpeed *= -0.5;
        }
    }

    if(upBumping){ 
        if(ySpeed < 0){
            ySpeed *= -0.5;
        }
    }  ////BUMPING

    if(downBumping){   //if touching the floor
        if(ySpeed > 0){
            ySpeed = 0;
            trace("1")
        }
        if(upPressed) { //y speed to jump constant
            ySpeed = jumpConstant;
            trace("2");
        }
    }   else { // if not touching the floor
             ySpeed += gravityConstant;  // moves downward
        trace("portobello");
    }

    if(xSpeed > maxSpeedConstant) { // lettin you move right
        xSpeed = maxSpeedConstant;
    } else if(xSpeed < (maxSpeedConstant * -1)) { // leting you move left
        xSpeed = (maxSpeedConstant * -1);
    }

    xSpeed *= friction;
    ySpeed *= friction;

    if(Math.abs(xSpeed) < 0.5) {
    xSpeed = 0;
}

    scrollX -= xSpeed;
    scrollY -= ySpeed;

    back.x = scrollX;
    back.y = scrollY;

    if( ( leftPressed || rightPressed || xSpeed > speedConstant || xSpeed < speedConstant *-1 ) && downBumping) {
    animationState = "running";
} else if(downBumping) {
    animationState = "idle";
} else {
    animationState = "jumping";
}
if (player.currentLabel != animationState) {
    player.gotoAndStop(animationState);
 }  

}

if (player.currentLabel != animationState) {
    player.gotoAndStop(animationState);
}

if (enemyList.length > 0) // if there are any enemies left in the enemyList
{
    for (var i:int = 0; i < enemyList.length; i++) // for each enemy in the enemyList
    {
        if (bulletList.length > 0) // if there are any bullets alive
        {
            for (var j:int = 0; j < bulletList.length; j++) // for each bullet in the bulletList
            {
                if ( enemyList[i].hitTestObject(bulletList[j]) )
                {
                    trace("Bullet and Enemy are colliding");
                    enemyList[i].removeSelf();
                    bulletList[j].removeSelf();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



function keyDownHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
        leftPressed = true;

    } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
        rightPressed = true;

    } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP){
        upPressed = true;

    } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN){
        downPressed = true;
    }   
}

function keyUpHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
        leftPressed = false;

    } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
        rightPressed = false;

    } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP){
        upPressed = false;

    } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN){
        downPressed = false;
    }   
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE) {
    fireBullet();
    }
}



function addEnemy(xLocation:int, yLocation:int): void {
    var enemy:Enemy = new Enemy(xLocation, yLocation);
    back.addChild(enemy);

    enemy.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED, enemyRemoved);
    enemyList.push(enemy);
}

function enemyRemoved(e:Event):void {
    e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED, enemyRemoved);
    enemyList.splice(enemyList.indexOf(e.currentTarget), 1);
}


function fireBullet():void {
    var playerDirection:String;
    if(player.scaleX < 0) {
        playerDirection = "left";
    } else if(player.scaleX > 0) {
        playerDirection = "right";
    }
    var bullet:Bullet = new Bullet(player.x, player.y, playerDirection);
    stage.addChild(bullet);
    // firing direction
}

function bulletRemoved(e:Event):void
{
    e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED, bulletRemoved); // stops and error from occuring in the event listener
    bulletList.splice(bulletList.indexOf(e.currentTarget), 1); // removes a bullet from the list
}
```

The enemy *.as* file:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Enemy extends MovieClip { 

        public function Enemy(xLocation:int, yLocation:int) {
            // constructor code
            x = xLocation;
            y = yLocation;

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
          }

        public function loop(e:Event):void {
            //looping code
          }

        public function removeSelf():void {
            trace("remove self");   
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop); //stops the loop
            this.parent.removeChild(this); // tell this objects "parent object" to remove said object
          }

        }

    }
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what your problem is, your added Enemy instances are not visible on the screen?   If that's the case, please explain what `back` is and it's context (which seems to be the parent of your enemy instance) - most likely `back` objects position combined with your enemy object's position makes it off screen.  It would be helpful though if you only posted the bare-minimum amount of code to reproduce the problem

Comment: The back is the stage the character moves on and i went to place objects on the stage for coordinates, one was supposed to spawn in front of my character but it didn't, and objects labeled enemy would be static non intractable objects.